# Mocha - running and resolving two async/await calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I am having a tough time getting this working.  I'm not able to get the second async call to run:

```
it.only('can delete an S3 bucket for a given PR', async() => {
  let result
  const options = { branch: '11'}
    // this runs and completes just fine (as you can see in the webstorm pic)
    await Deploy.createPRBucket(options, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      console.log(`created error: ${error}`)
      console.log(`created stdout: ${stdout}`)
      console.log(`created stderr: ${stderr}`)
      result = JSON.parse(stdout)
      console.log("added")
    })

    // it never hits my console log and bombs before that right after the createPRBucket call resolves
    console.log("deleting...")
    await Deploy.deletePRBucket(options.branch, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      console.log(`deleted error: ${error}`)
      console.log(`deleted stdout: ${stdout}`)
      console.log(`deleted stderr: ${stderr}`)
      expect(stdout).to.exist
    })
})
```

**The Code**:

```
export async function createPRBucket (options, callback){
  try {
    await exec(`aws s3api create-bucket --bucket ${options.branch} --region us-west-2 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=us-west-2`,
      (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);

      callback(error, stdout, stderr)
      // process.exit(0)
    })
    let error, stdout, stderr

  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(`there was a problem creating this bucket: ${err}`)
    // process.exit(1)
  }
}

export async function deletePRBucket(branch, callback){

    await exec(`aws s3 rb s3://xxx-${branch} --force`,
      (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);

        callback(error, stdout, stderr)
        // process.exit(0)
      })
}
```

Here's what I see in WebStorm:
[image]
**Note**: The picture shows that I have `(done) =>` and `done()` but took those out since I'm using `async () =>`.  Either way I arrive at the same problem, same error regardless.

Also **Note** that I can put a breakpoint inside the callback of the first await call (createPRBranch) in my test and it gets it just fine.  But if I put a breakpoint in the second call (await for deletePRBranch), the second never gets hit, nor does that call resolve.

Comment: `createPRBucket` and `deletePRBucket` don't return anything, so because they are `async` they'll return a Promise resolved to `undefined` - therefore await in the calling function won't wait for the asynchronous operation to complete

Comment: I've also tried taking await completely out of the two calls in my mocha test.  It just ignores the promise if I keep await in there I think but removing await didn't help or change he problem either

Comment: hold on let me update the post a bit

Comment: Not sure what the new "images" prove - I've told you the problem - does `exec` even return a Promise?

Comment: yes it does because I'm using Node v8's  new util.promisify...so yes exact promisfies the exec() call.   So I guess I'm not getting what you're trying to say or at least what the resolution is here...I'm missing something you're inferring that I'm not

Comment: why are you using callback's if exec is promisified :p

Comment: exec is promisfied.  And why am I using callbacks?  Because I don't know another way to get at stdout, error, ect after the exec is done...how would I get those?

Comment: as promises resolve/reject a single value, how do `error, stdout, stderr` "map" to the resolved/rejected value?

Comment: that's what I wasn't sure about...the only way I was able to get to those values was via a callback. If you know a better way I'm all ears.  I'm still fairly new to promises and async/await both..so there might be nuances I'm missing at times.

Comment: the await yields (resolves) the promisfied exec() but I don't know how I'd get to the stdout, etc from my tests if I take out that callback. if that's the case if I remove the callback.  There's a grey area for me here, that might me obvious to you.

Comment: I spent hours on it actually before posting this issue, so just fyi, the pain was felt already and I know most of the things you pointed out but just couldn't get my hand at refactoring this to a better place, I didn't want to post this but had to in the end and get help with it...tried many things with no luck.  I knew it was something stupid simple but I just couldn't get to that place this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given that exec is a util.promisifed child_process.exec

```
it.only('can delete an S3 bucket for a given PR', async() => {
    let result;
    const options = { branch: '11' };
        // this runs and completes just fine (as you can see in the webstorm pic)
    let {stdout, stderr} = await Deploy.createPRBucket(options);
    console.log(`created error: ${error}`);
    console.log(`created stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.log(`created stderr: ${stderr}`);
    result = JSON.parse(stdout);
    console.log("added");
    console.log("deleting...");

    ({stdout, stderr} = await Deploy.deletePRBucket(options.branch));
    console.log(`deleted error: ${error}`);
    console.log(`deleted stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.log(`deleted stderr: ${stderr}`);
    expect(stdout).to.exist
})
```

The exported functions can simply be - note, no need for `async` as they return a Promise already

```
export function createPRBucket(options) {
    return exec(`aws s3api create-bucket --bucket ${options.branch} --region us-west-2 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=us-west-2`);
}

export function deletePRBucket(branch) {
    return exec(`aws s3 rb s3://xxx-${branch} --force`);
}
```

The promise returned by the promisified exec resolves to

```
{ stdout: "...", stderr: "..." }
```

> Note: I haven't tested for error condition of `exec` - the error object is

```
{ 
  killed: true or false, 
  code: a number?, 
  signal: null (not sure what else can be here, 
  cmd: "the original command line that was run"
}
```

explanation of

```
({stdout, stderr} = await Deploy.deletePRBucket(options.branch));
```

> The ( .. ) around the assignment statement is required syntax when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.
>
> {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2} is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the {a, b} on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.
>
> However, ({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}) is valid, as is var {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}
>
> NOTE: Your ( ..) expression needs to be preceded by a semicolon or it may be used to execute a function on the previous line.
>
> source: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration)

Comment: omg that's awesome, I didn't think about the fact that you could use destructuring for this

Comment: really appreciate your look at my code, I needed a second pair of eyes and maybe someone who had a little more experience than I did with it.

Comment: Where I went grey was I didn't understand what exactly got yieleded with the await on the promisfied exec(). I didn't know what exec returned when resolved.  I suppose it's obvious to some (hey look they had an example resolving it via a callback function) but I it's hard for me to envision the "resolve" here when that's all wrapped in a promise...then yielded via await

Comment: you also didn't actually return anything in those exported functions, rather, you were still using the callback paradigm. Which resulted in the promises returned by those functions being resolved immediately

Comment: yea I know...:).  I knew that it was a f'd up way I was trying to do things but just needed some guidance on it.  I knew some things were being "ignored" but didn't know how to really get it to a better place

Comment: btw, your second { error, stdout, stderr }  causes a syntax error on = "expression expected"

Comment: interesting, so when you surrounded the second destructuring with () what did that do exctly?

Comment: Added explanation of `({...} = ...)` to answer

Comment: thanks a lot!!  that's new to me on more `advanced` destructuring..getting there slowly :)

Comment: personally, I'd be more inclined to do `let result = await ...` and `result = await ...` the second time, and just use `result.stdout` / `result.stderr` in the following code

Comment: today I actually got the following error for the () you put around the second await: `TypeError: (0 , _context4.t0) is not a function`

Comment: but if I do this, it works:       let { failure, success, payload } = await deployApi.createBucket(options)

      let { failure1, success1, payload1 } = await deployApi.deleteBucket(options.branch)

Comment: so this is not working actually I found: ({stdout, stderr} = await Deploy.deletePRBucket(options.branch));

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469366/reuse-object-literals-created-via-destructuring

Comment: See the second last sentence in this answer - **Your ( ..) expression needs to be preceded by a semicolon or it may be used to execute a function on the previous line.** - if you'd heeded that advice rather than sticking to your "I don't use semicolons" mindset, you would not have had to ask that other question :p