# Reuse object literals created via destructuring

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I am trying to reuse the object literals for both async calls.  At the end my expect should check the success of the deleteBucket call.  Problem is I can't do this, or it says I've got dup variables defined:

```
it('can delete a bucket', async () => {
      const options = { branch: '11' }

      let { failure, success, payload } = await deployApi.createBucket(options)
      let { failure, success, payload} = await deployApi.deleteBucket(options.branch)

      expect(success).to.be.true
    })
```

Someone told me I could put a () around the second, but that's bombing out giving me a `TypeError: (0 , _context4.t0) is not a function` error:

```
it('can delete a bucket', async () => {
  const options = { branch: '11' }

  let { failure, success, payload } = await deployApi.createBucket(options)

  ({ failure, success, payload} = await deployApi.deleteBucket(options.branch))

  expect(success).to.be.true
})
```

This does work, but requires me to change the names of the resolved objects which I do not want to do:

```
it('can delete a bucket', async () => {
      const options = { branch: '11' }

      let { failure, success, payload } = await deployApi.createBucket(options)
      let { failure1, success1, payload1} = await deployApi.deleteBucket(options.branch)

      expect(success1).to.be.true
    })
```

UPDATE:

someone suggested I needed a semi colon after the const line.  Didn't make any difference, I still get the same error when I run it:

[image]

Comment: I see your update including screenshot. Can you please read my answer more closely? It shows precisely where you need to put the semicolon. Your screenshot shows a semicolon in the wrong (unnecessary) location

Comment: FYI, `async/await` is not part of ES6 (ES2015). It is part of this year's release, ES2017.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**missing semicolon**

You have two `(...)` sequenced together -

```js
await deployApi.createBucket(options)  

({ failure, success, payload} = await deployApi.deleteBucket(options.branch))
```

ES interpreter sees this as -

```js
await deployApi.createBucket(options)(... await deployApi.deleteBucket(options.branch))
```

Which is equivalent to -

```js
const r1 = deployApi.createBucket(options)
const r2 = r1(... await deployApi.deleteBucket(options.branch))
await r2
```

Which is very different than your actual intention -

```js
const r1 = await deployApi.createBucket(...)
const r2 = await deployApi.deleteBucket(...)
```

To reuse the `let` destructured object, the parentheses are required -

```js
// initial assignment
let { a, b, c } = ...

// without the parentheses, ES interprets as illegal assignment using =
{ a, b, c } = ...

// with parentheses, ES interprets as destructuring assignment
({ a, b, c } = ...)
```

If you reuse the same `let` bindings, the **required** parentheses change the meaning of your program when the semicolon is not used.

```js
it('can delete a bucket', async () => {
  const options = { branch: '11' }
                                                           // semicolon here
  let { failure, success, payload } = await deployApi.createBucket(options); 
  
  ({ failure, success, payload} = await deployApi.deleteBucket(options.branch))
  
  expect(success).to.be.true
})
```

Comment: well not sure where that would be because if I change the delete function to return a 1 on the end, my test works fine.  So that tells me it's a code issue on the implementation side.

Comment: I'm returning things the very same way the createBucket does

Comment: I don't use semi colons, my eslint doesn't care if I leave them out

Comment: wait where did I need the semi colon?

Comment: On the `let` line, as illustrated and commented in my post

Comment: didn't make a difference in fact eslint told me it was unecessary.  I tried it, still getting the same error

Comment: yeah well something is wrong with your linter/preprocessor configuration then – it's 100% an automatic semicolon insertion (ASI) issue. See my updated answer to show how I recreated the problem.

Comment: @PositiveGuy: You have to put the semicolon after the first `await` call, not `const`. `foo() <line break> (whatever here)` is interpreted as `foo()(whatever here)`, i.e. two function calls. The parenthesis you put around the `{...} = ...` assignment are not interpreted as grouping operator but as function call (`{} = ...` being the argument passed to the call). Semicolons matter. You wouldn't have that problem if you simply always used them ;)

Comment: ah ok got it, you are right, I was trying to put it in the wrong spot, sorry I didn't read, long night.  Thanks much for helping!